# A generic enum as passed parameter

Tags: c#, generics, methods, enums

Say I want to create a method that accepts enum instead of a string so I could specify a parameter instead of writing string value representing the passed parameter.

For instance, let's say mods are strings of names so each of the variants has items of it's own and do has to place a call to chosen item.

```
   public void DoWithMode(chosenMod parModifier)
   {
       string SelectedM = parModifier.ToString();
       dedicateLineTo(Seleted...) or something
   }

  public class Com
  {
      public enum chosenMode{dummy1, dummy2};
  }
  public class Tel:Com
  {
     public new emum chosenMode {Telmod1, Telmod2};
     public Tel
     {
         DoWithMode(chosenMode.Tel1mode);
     }
  }

  class fax:Com
  {
      emum new chosenMode {Faxmod1, Faxmod2}; 
      public fax
      {
          DoWithMode(chosenMode.Faxmod2);
      }
  }
```

What if I would like to make a generic `ChosenMode`. Say, for example, phone and fax have some common usage with the `Do()`  method, i could make some overrides but this is only 2 kinds what if I have 20 or more classes and each has its own items to pass?

So it's only strings or method overrides though I was thinking of the comfortable usage of enum rather a class of const strings.

What is the workaround for this case?

I could do something else using enum type but then intellisense would not auto-suggest it so i would need to write something like

```
DoSomething(namespaceA.classT.subclassV.classX....class.modifier.item)
```